# Python http server stop responding after 2 requests

Tags: python, httpserver

i am sending http post data to http server from a form on webpage , first 2 requests works fine but most of the times when I send 3rd request , it does not receive the request
however in some instances i did noticed that the server do not receives the request on second request as well , but it does not happen too often, on the third request it causes the issue more often

what happens is when i send the first request , it instantly receives and process the data , on the second request it does the same , but on third request it does not receives anything and the web page keep showing the loading sign and after few more seconds the webpage gives the error that the the site can be reached and that the 123.12.12.12 took too long to respond

**here is the code**

```
import os
import kwargs
import args
import csv
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import logging
import urllib.parse

class S(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
def _set_response(self):
    self.send_response(200)
    #self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
    #self.end_headers()

def breakRequest(self, str):
    l = []
    x = str.split("&")
    for i in x:
        a = i.split("=")
        l.append(a[1])
    return l[0], l[1], l[2], l[3], l[4]

def do_POST(self):
    content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length']) 
    post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length) 
    var1,var2,var3,var4,var5 = self.breakRequest(str(post_data.decode('utf-8')))
    s = "\n"   +var1+  "\n"  +var2+  "\n"  +var3+  "\n"  +var4+  "\n"  +var5+  "\n"
    logging.info(s)
    #logging.info("POST request,\nPath: %s\\n%s\n\nBody:\n%s\n",
    str(self.path), str(self.headers), post_data.decode('utf-8')
    #print (urllib.parse.unquote(var5))
    pass


    if (var5 == str("1")):
        with open(r'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Received\Files\file1.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow([var1])
            writer.writerow([var2])
            writer.writerow([var3])
            writer.writerow([var4])

            

    self._set_response()
    self.wfile.write("Done {}".format(self.path).encode('utf-8'))        

    if (var5 == str("2")):
        with open(r'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Received\Files\file2.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow([var1])
            writer.writerow([var2])
            writer.writerow([var3])
            writer.writerow([var4])

    self._set_response()
    self.wfile.write("Done {}".format(self.path).encode('utf-8'))                

    if (var5 == str("3")):
        with open(r'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Received\Files\file3.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow([var1])
            writer.writerow([var2])
            writer.writerow([var3])
            writer.writerow([var4])
    self._set_response()
    self.wfile.write("Done {}".format(self.path).encode('utf-8'))     

def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=S, port= int(input("enter the serving port"))):
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    server_address = ('', port)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    logging.info('Starting httpd...\n')
    try:
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    httpd.server_close()
    logging.info('Stopping httpd...\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from sys import argv

    if len(argv) == 2:
        run(port=int(argv[1]))
    else:
        run()
```

Comment: Could you please include the requests your sending? What exactly do you do in the browser / curl?

Comment: Its a simple http post request 
i have a simple HTML form once user inputs the data and click on the submit button then the form data is sent to the server in this format " key1=abc&key2=123&key3=hjkl&key4=asdf&key5=2"